# How can I initialize an object with a null value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, nonetype, python-typing

```py
class FileCompoundDefinition(AbstractCompoundDefinition):
    # <editor-fold desc="(type declaration)">
    __include_dependency_graph: IncludeDepGraphTagFL
    __inner_namespace: InnerNamespaceTag
    __brief_description: BriefDescription
    __detailed_description: DetailedDescription
    __location: LocationDefinitionCL
    # </editor-fold>

    # <editor-fold desc="(constructor)">
    def __init__(self,
                 id: str,
                 kind: str,
                 language: str,
                 compound_name: str):
        super().__init__(id, kind, compound_name)
        self.__language = language
        self.__includes_list = []
        self.__inner_class_list = []
        self.__include_dependency_graph = None
        self.__inner_namespace = None
        self.__brief_description = None
        self.__detailed_description = None
        self.__location = None
    # </editor-fold>
```

In the above source code, the following lines are showing errors:

```py
self.__include_dependency_graph = None
self.__inner_namespace = None
self.__brief_description = None
self.__detailed_description = None
self.__location = None
```

[image]

How can I initialize an object with a `None` value?

Comment: Those are just warning because those variables have type annotations, and they are not marked as `Optional` making it wrong to set them as `None`. Change the annotations to be `Optional[<type>]` and those warning should go away

Comment: Why do you think your static type checker wouldn't complain if you tried to assign a value of the wrong type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) the following doesn't cause any warnings.

```py
from typing import Optional

class FileCompoundDefinition(AbstractCompoundDefinition):

    __location: Optional[LocationDefinitionCL]

    def __init__(...)

    self.__location = None
    ...
    self.__location = LocationDefinitionCL()
```

See

> [PEP 484 - Union types](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types)
>
> As a shorthand for `Union[T1, None]` you can write `Optional[T1]`; for example, the above is equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> from typing import Optional
>
> def handle_employee(e: Optional[Employee]) -> None: ...
> ```